# Set a Session inside Javascript in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this is possibe inside a js function

```
<% session[:comment] = "This is the comment" %>
```

But is there any way to make this work.

```
var comment = "This is the comment";
<% session[:comment] = comment %>
```

Because in my app I get this comment from a text field. So i have to set the string dynamically. So is there a way I can make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think u can set session in this way.

But a solution will be to use cookies instead of session.

There are JS plugins to set cookies and you can use them in your ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly. The javascript part runs on the client side and hence you cant insert the values into a server side variable without sending it back to the server. You will have to use ajax calls to do it.

This quora post should help : http://www.quora.com/Ruby-on-Rails-web-framework/Can-I-pass-a-JavaScript-variable-to-a-Rails-method

Comment: So I cant set this session.. So sad.
I cant use ajax because as soon as this comment gets set another url is getting caled

Comment: You can always place an ajax call before the next url is hit. Need more insight on your code for the exact solution.

Comment: actualy there is a text field.. and using jquery onchange im saving its value in comments variable. I have an a tag with onclick im going to another url which is out from the project(fb_share_page). and on closing that page fb automatically gives a '/fb_close' url. and with which I moves to another controller method.

Comment: I want this comment in that controller. As i cant set any params in fb_close.. i want to set session.

Comment: Before the redirection (inside the on change itself it can be done judging by the looks of it) you need to make an ajax call and store it in a persistent variable(maybe a static variable or global constant or DB). After this ajax call completes you can proceed with the other options inside the success block for the ajax call.